# Local notifications with repeat function for specific dates

Tags: ios, time, notifications, swift4, picker

I have time picker set up. Local notification takes time from the time picker and sends the notification.

I have three notification with identifiers notfica2, notifica3 and notifica 4.

Now, I want to repeat notifica 2 and notifica3 every weekday (Monday to Friday) and repeat notifica 4 every weekend (Saturday-Sunday).

I didn't pick dates for the notificas. So I think timePicker automatically picks the date the time was set.

Please show me how to implement this specific repeat option.

Also, I have another bug. Lets say when I am picking the time it is 5 pm. And I want to set time 3 pm for notifica2 and notifica3 (which I want to repeat every weekday)

The exception says negative time. I understand the issue but I need a fix. So, if I put 3 pm but its already 6 pm then the 3pm notification will be sent the next day if it is not Saturday or Sunday. Same with notifica 4. But instead this will shift by 5 days for next Saturday.

Here is my code so far.
This is a small part of a larger app.

var textfield: UITextField!

```
let timePicker = UIDatePicker()
let timePicker2 = UIDatePicker()
let timePicker3 = UIDatePicker()



func timePickerFunction(){
    //toolbar
    timePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    timePicker2.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time
    timePicker3.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.time


    let toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    //DoneButton
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector (donePressed))
    toolBar.setItems([doneButton], animated: false)

    BWTimePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    AWTimePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
    ODTimePicker.inputAccessoryView = toolBar

    //Assigning timepicker to the text fields
    BWTimePicker.inputView = timePicker
    AWTimePicker.inputView = timePicker2
    ODTimePicker.inputView = timePicker3


}

func donePressed(){

    //Formatting the date.
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateStyle = .none
    dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short




    //            BWTimePicker.text = "\(timePicker.date)"
    //            AWTimePicker.text = "\(timePicker.date)"
    //            ODTimePicker.text = "\(timePicker.date)"
    //            self.view.endEditing(true)

    if BWTimePicker.isEditing {
        //do something to textfield1
        BWTimePicker.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    else if AWTimePicker.isEditing {
        //do something to textfield2
        AWTimePicker.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker2.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    else if ODTimePicker.isEditing {
        //do something to textfield2
        ODTimePicker.text = dateFormatter.string(from: timePicker3.date)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    //            self.view.endEditing(true)

}


@IBAction func updateTime(_ sender: UIButton) {

    //1. Get text from three UITextField objects.

    let stringBW = BWTimePicker.text

    let stringAW = AWTimePicker.text

    let stringOD = ODTimePicker.text

    //2. If the three time fields are not empty , we would send the notificaiton

    if !(stringBW?.isEmpty)! && !(stringAW?.isEmpty)! && !(stringOD?.isEmpty)! {

        //3. We would create a dictionary object which would be send in the notification

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hi!", arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Your Satisfier Quote is Ready", arguments: nil)
        content.categoryIdentifier = "time-test"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        var timeInterval1: Double = 0
        var timeInterval2: Double = 0
        var timeInterval3: Double = 0

        let date = timePicker.date
        let date2 = timePicker2.date
        let date3 = timePicker3.date


        timeInterval1 =  date.timeIntervalSinceNow
        timeInterval2 =  date2.timeIntervalSinceNow
        timeInterval3 =  date3.timeIntervalSinceNow

        print("HMMMMMMMMMKMKMKMKSMKDMSKDMSK")
        print(timeInterval1)
        print(timeInterval2)
        print(timeInterval3)

        setNotification(timeInterval:timeInterval1,identifier: "notific2", date: date)
        setNotification(timeInterval:timeInterval2,identifier: "notific3", date: date2)
        setNotification(timeInterval:timeInterval3,identifier: "notific4", date: date3)


        self.isProfileViewVisible = true
        self.extraViewTopConstraint2.constant = 1000
        self.profileViewTopConstraint.constant = 150

    }

    else{

        //2. Ask user to enter text in all the fields.

        self.isProfileViewVisible = true
        self.extraViewTopConstraint2.constant = 1000
        self.profileViewTopConstraint.constant = 150


    }
}

func setNotification (timeInterval : Double, identifier : String, date : Date){

    let A: Int = 0
    let B: Int = codeTwo.count
    let C: Int = codeOne.count
    let D: Int = codeThree.count

    let number1 = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(B - 1)))
    let number2 = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(C - 1)))
    let number3 = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(D - 1)))

    //Repeat fundtion only added to notifica 2 for experimaental purpose/

    if(identifier == "notific2"){
        let content: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
        content.category = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hey there!", arguments: nil)
        content.alertBody = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "\(codeTwo[number1])", arguments: nil)
        //content.categoryIdentifier = "time-test"
        content.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName

        let time =  date

        content.fireDate = time
        content.repeatInterval = NSCalendar.Unit.day


        //            let triggerDate =  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: time as Date)
        //
        //            let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
        //                                                        repeats: true)
        //
        //            //let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true)
        //            let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)
        //
        //            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        //            center.add(request)

        UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(content)

    }
    if(identifier == "notific3"){
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hey there!", arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "\(codeThree[number3])", arguments: nil)
        //content.categoryIdentifier = "time-test"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }

    if(identifier == "notific4"){
        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "Hey there!", arguments: nil)
        content.body = NSString.localizedUserNotificationString(forKey: "\(codeOne[number2])", arguments: nil)
        //content.categoryIdentifier = "time-test"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()

        let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.init(timeInterval: timeInterval, repeats: true)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest.init(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request)
    }

}

//MARK: ViewController lifeCycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.customization()
    self.collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
    searchBar.delegate = self
    //searchBar.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.done
    items = items1
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    timePickerFunction()

    // (sender as AnyObject).setTitle("Add to Group", for: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
        options: [.alert,.sound])
    {
        (granted, error) in
        self.notificationGranted = granted
        if let error = error {
            print("granted, but Error in notification permission:\(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This is way to much (and poorly formatted) code. Please only post code relevant to your question and please format it properly.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is my first time posting. The formatting style got changed when I posted here for some reason.